# Topological definition of intersection multiplicities of algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I posted this question in Stack Exchange and was recommended the appendix of Fulton's Young Tableaux. While I think it's good, it'd be nice to have some books which explain this subject in more detail.

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over the field of complex numbers.
In other words, $X$ is a reduced separable scheme of finite type over the field of complex numbers.
Let $U$ and $V$ be irreducible subvarieities of X.
Let $W$ be an irreducible component of $U ∩ V$.
Suppose $W$ contains a closed non-singular point of $X$.
In other words, the local ring of $X$ at $W$ is regular.
Then dim $U$ + dim $V$ $≦$ dim $X$ + dim $W$
If the equality holds, one says that $U$ and $V$ intersect properly at $W$.
In this case, a non negative integer called intersection multiplicity $i(U, V, W; X)$ is defined
algebraically(see, for example, Serre's Local Algebra).
I heard that this number can be defined by methods of algebraic topology.
Is there any book which explains this in detail?

**Edit**
The notion of intersection multiplicities is at the heart of algebraic geometry.
For example, Weil's book "Foundations of algebraic geometry" is almost entirely devoted on this subject.

Comment: Makoto, in the future, please provide links when you cross-post, so people can see what others have written (without having to search for it), so that people don't write a bunch of stuff only to find out someone else already wrote it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136574/topological-definition-of-intersection-multiplicities-of-algebraic-varieties

Comment: I didn't know how to link. Now I know it and I will do so.